# Android mobile micro usb port as clock pulse generator

Tags: android, serial-port, arduino, microcontroller, android-hardware

I am working on a project which requires android phone to generate clock pulse through micro USB port. I would request your help, and would like to know if this is possible and if it is? How should i go about doing it?
I have tried reading about audio jack generating clock pulses, although this is interesting but I would like to explore usb port for generating PWM clock pulses.
I am not an expert in communication but really interested to understand and more specifically in the above mentioned context. 
PS: Although i respect Arduino, IOIO boards but the constraint is i cannot use them in this project.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

We can make the datan outof USB in such a way that it matches the pwm pulse.data is always high r low so as the PWM. send may highs according to ur pulse width this also depends on the clock change the clock speed such that it matches switching frequency.